# Rename a column with a '.' using sql function sp_rename

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I used a query to alter my table column name as follows:

```
exec sp_rename 'Mobile.Mobileno','Mobile.MobileNum','COLUMN'
```

Now that I know I had made a mistake by taking the new column name as 'Mobile.MobileNum', is there a way to solve it.

Since when I am using the above query again, I am facing an error.

```
exec sp_rename 'Mobile.Mobile.MobileNum','MobileNum','COLUMN'
```

PS: Cannot drop the table or column

Comment: Could you paste your error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to escape the erroneous column name with `[..]`:

```
exec sp_rename 'Mobile.[Mobile.MobileNum]','MobileNum','COLUMN'
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9fab/1)